# Flutter Web: stream on browserwindow resize keeps waiting

Tags: flutter, firebase, web, stream

I'm trying to load data from firebase firestore with my flutter webapp as stream. And this works fine until I resize the browser window. Then the stream is stuck in the ConnectionState.Waiting if clause.

Any idea why?

Code:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<Contact?>(
            stream: ContactDataService.getContactById(id),
            builder: (context, contactSnapshot) {
              if (contactSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return LoadingWidget();
              }

              if (contactSnapshot.data == null) {
                return Center(
                    child: SizedBox(
                  width: 600,
                  child: ErrorCard(
                      message: 'Error: ' +
                          contactSnapshot.error.toString()),
                ));
              }

              Contact contact = contactSnapshot.data!;

              return Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: CustomSubScaffoldWrapper(
                    appActions: _contactActions(contact, context),
                    subScaffoldPages:
                        _contactPages(contact, contactScaffoldKey),
                    intialPage: widget.selectedPage,
                    subScaffoldKey: contactScaffoldKey,
                  ))
                ],
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

Application:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem. I don't really know why it is that why, but the problem hadn't to do anything with the stream itself. In some way my widget structure blocked the streams.
To solve this a extracted the stream part of my widget into an own widget and voila it worked.

Now with the following code my stream don't stuck on waiting anymore:

Stream-Wrapper-Widget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:objectgo/models/db/contact.dart';
import 'package:objectgo/providers/property_management_provider.dart';
import 'package:objectgo/services/data/contact_data_service.dart';
import 'package:objectgo/widgets/error_card.dart';
import 'package:objectgo/widgets/loading_widget.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ContactDetailsStreamWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContactDetailsStreamWrapper(this.contactId,
      {required this.builder, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  final String contactId;
  final Widget Function(Contact contact) builder;

  @override
  State<ContactDetailsStreamWrapper> createState() =>
      _ContactDetailsStreamWrapperState();
}

class _ContactDetailsStreamWrapperState
    extends State<ContactDetailsStreamWrapper> {
  Stream<Contact?>? contactStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    contactStream = ContactDataService.getContactById(
        context.read<PropertyManagementProvider>().currentPropertyManagementId!,
        widget.contactId);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<Contact?>(
        stream: contactStream,
        builder: (context, contactSnapshot) {
          if (contactSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return LoadingWidget();
          }

          if (contactSnapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
                child: SizedBox(
              width: 600,
              child: ErrorCard(
                  message: 'Das Unternehmen konnte nicht geladen werden \n' +
                      contactSnapshot.error.toString()),
            ));
          }
          return widget.builder(contactSnapshot.data!);
        });
  }
}
```